# What ansatz means?

Tags: definition

I often see (in the case of ODE) : Let $\dot x=f(x)+\varepsilon g(x)$ and ODE. We make the ansatz that $x(t)=Ae^{\frac{g(x)}{\varepsilon }}.$ What does it mean ? In [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ansatz) is not well explained. Does it mean that "we suppose that $x(t)=Ae^{\frac{g(x)}{\varepsilon }}$" ? If yes, why can we suppose that ?

Comment: From Google, "an assumption about the form of an unknown function which is made in order to facilitate solution of an equation or other problem."

Comment: Can mathematicians stop using obscure words? Writing it as the English word 'guess' is just fine.

Answer (score 3):

The Wikipedia article describes an *ansatz* as "an educated guess that is verified later by its results". I think that this is quite a good description.

Often we know that a solution must have a certain form. Perhaps you have learnt some rules about how to assert particular solutions of nonhomogeneous first order differential equations, e.g. for $y''(x) + 2 y'(x) + 3 y(x) = x^3$ assert $y_p(x) = a x^3 + b x^2 + c x + d$ and determine $a,b,c,d$. This can be considered to be an ansatz.

In other cases we think that a solution probably can be written on a certain form, for example like $y(x) = f(x) e^x$, and that such an assertion will make solving the equation easier. This is another form of ansatz.

Answer (score 0):

"Ansatz" is German but is also used in English. It translates to "approach". So basically you make the *approach* $x(t)=Ae^{\frac{g(x)}{\varepsilon}}$ and then show that this choice of $x$ does indeed solve your ODE.

Comment: It also can be translated as ‘starting point’.